# Borel $\sigma$-algebra on subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

I am trying to understand this remark but have some difficulties.

More precisely, denote by $\mathcal{M}=\{B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n): B\cap E\in \mathcal{E}\}$, where $\mathcal{E}=\sigma(S)$ and $S=\{E\cap U: U\ \text{is open in}\ \mathbb{R}^n\}$.

I have shown that all properties of $\sigma$-algebra for $\mathcal{M}$ are true, except complement property.

Suppose $A\in \mathcal{M}$ then $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $A\cap E\in \mathcal{E}$. Then we have to show that $\mathbb{R}^n-A\in \mathcal{M}$. Easy to see that $\mathbb{R}^n-A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. But I don't know how to show that $(\mathbb{R}^n-A)\cap E\in \mathcal{E}$.

I know that $\mathcal{E}$ is $\sigma$-algebra. But I don't know on what set it is $\sigma$-algebra.

Would be very grateful if anyone can show detailed answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{E}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ meaning, for the record, that it is a family of subsets of $E$ that is closed under taking complements (*with respect to $E$*) and countable unions and it contains the empty set.

As for your other question, $(\mathbb{R}^n - A) \cap E = (\mathbb{R}^n \cap E) - (A \cap E) = E - (A \cap E)$. Do you see why this has to be in $\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: Thanks for reply! But let me ask you one question: How do you know that $\mathcal{E}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$? I have problems with this.

Comment: If $\mathcal{E}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra *on $E$* and $A\cap E\in \mathcal{E}$ then indeed $E-(A\cap E)\in \mathcal{E}$. But the question why is $\mathcal{E}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$?

Comment: It is, by definition, "the $\sigma$-algebra generated by intersections of $E$ with open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$". (The generated $\sigma$-algebra of some family of sets is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing every element of the family. It is thus, as the name suggests, a $\sigma$-algebra.)

Comment: Sorry for this dumb question, I understood your last comment and I know the definition of $\sigma$-algebra generated by some family of sets $\mathcal{F}$. But it is not clear to me why $\mathcal{E}$ is $\sigma$-algebra on $E$.

Comment: We have that $\mathcal{E}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra generated by set $S$, where $S=\{E\cap V: V \text{open in}\ \mathbb{R}^n\}$, i.e. $\mathcal{E}$  is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $S$. But $\mathcal{E}$ is $\sigma$-algebra on what set? You concluded that it is $\sigma$-algebra on $E$, but it not clear to me. Could you explain it?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I see your problem now. I think that in the text they implicitly mean that $\mathcal{E}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on E. The general convention is that for a family of sets $\mathcal{F}$ the generated $\sigma$-algebra is meant with respect to the base set $\cup \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Could you explain your last sentence? What do you mean by "is meant with respect to the base set $\cup \mathcal{F}$"?

Comment: $\cup \mathcal{F} = \{x \in F : F \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is the base set of the family of sets $\mathcal{F}$. (In your case this will just be $E$.) Taking the generated $\sigma$-algebra with respect to this set means that you take the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{F}$ from the $\sigma$-algebras on this set (in particular taking complement is only meant with respect to this set).

Comment: Your last comment is quite weird. Let me explain why. If $X$ is a space and $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of subsets of $X$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}\subset 2^X$. In my book when author proves that $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ exists he consider the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras on X containing $\mathcal{F}$, and this intersection is not empty since there is at least one such $\sigma$-algebra which is $2^X$. So we get that $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ is $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ containing $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Note that in my last sentence $\sigma$-algebra is on $X$, not the set which you described. So I guess that my question is still need answer.

Comment: $\mathcal{F} \subseteq 2^{\cup \mathcal{F}}$ always holds, so in this way my notion is consistent with the one in your book. Of course you could consider $\mathcal{F}$ as a family of subsets of some larger base set as well; then you get a different generated $\sigma$-algebra. As I said, the convention is that, unless otherwise specified, the generated $\sigma$-algebra is meant with respect to the smallest possible base set, which is $\cup \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: I can't understand why your notion is consistent with the book's one. In my opinion your notion and the book's one are distinct. I am beginner in measure theory so would be very grateful if you can explain it to me, please

Comment: Also, i have never me the notion of base set and it is quite confusing, to be honest

Comment: Could you explain me your last comment please in a detail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85270/discussion-between-relep-and-rfz).